# ggplot geom_bar: meaning of aes(group = 1)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am learning *geom_bar* on section 3.7 of r4ds.had.co.nz. I run a code like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., group = 1))
```

Then I have this plot:
[image: click here]

The point is, if I exclude the "group = 1" part:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop..))
```

The plot will be wrong, [image: like this]

But if I replace group = 1 by group = 2 or group = "x", the plot still looks correct. So I don't quite understand the meaning of group = 1 here and how to use it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`group="whatever"` is a "dummy" grouping to override the default behavior, which (here) is to group by `cut` and in general is to group by the x variable. The default for `geom_bar` is to group by the x variable in order to separately count the number of rows in each level of the x variable. For example, here, the default would be for `geom_bar` to return the number of rows with `cut` equal to "Fair", "Good", etc.

However, if we want proportions, then we need to consider all levels of `cut` together. In the second plot, the data are first grouped by `cut`, so each level of `cut` is considered separately. The proportion of Fair in Fair is 100%, as is the proportion of Good in Good, etc. `group=1` (or `group="x"`, etc.) prevents this, so that the proportions of each level of cut will be relative to all levels of cut.

Comment: Does this mean that these are equivalent? `geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = after_stat(prop), group=1))` and `geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = after_stat(count/sum(count))))`?

Answer (score 2):

Group will help the plot to look at the specific rows that contain the specific cut and the proportion is found with respect to the whole database as in proportion of an ideal cut in the whole dataset.

If group is not used, the proportion is calculated with respect to the data that contains that field and is ultimately going to be 100% in any case. For instance, The proportion of an ideal cut in the ideal cut specific data will be 1.