# Color aes disconnects geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot, and show different colors when p > 0.5, but when I use the color aes, the line appears to be disconnected.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(n = 1:365)

prob <- function (x) {
  pr <- 1
  for (t in 2:x) {
    pr <- pr * ((365 - t + 1) / 365) 
  }
  return(1 - pr)
}


data %>%
  mutate(prob = map_dbl(n, prob)) %>%
  filter(n < 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = prob, color = prob > 0.5)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))
```

Anyone knows why? Removing the color `aes()` provides an unique line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `prob` is a discrete variable and condition `prob > 0.5` is splitting your data into two parts, with gap between them: the first half has `max(prob)` = .476 and the second half has `min(prob)` = .507. Hence, the (vertical) gap on the line plot is the gap between this numbers.

you can see it, if you filter modified *data* for values close to .5:

```
data %>%
  mutate(prob = map_dbl(n, prob)) %>%
  filter(n < 100) %>%
  filter(between(prob, .4, .6))
```

if we modify your example:

```
data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(prob = map_dbl(n, prob)) %>%
  filter(n < 100)

#bringing extremes closer together
data2$prob[22] <- .49999999999999
data2$prob[23] <- .50000000000001

data2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = prob, color = prob >= 0.5)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))
```

The gap becomes significantly smaller:

[image: Line plot with the gap]

However, it is still present (mostly on horizontal level) - because x variable is also discrete

A simple way of fixing this is to add dummy aesthetic `group = 1` inside `aes()`, which overrides default grouping by `x` variable.

```
data %>%
  mutate(prob = map_dbl(n, prob)) %>%
  filter(n < 100) %>%
#add 'group = 1' below
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = prob, color = prob >= 0.5, group = 1)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))
```

[image: Line plot without the gap]

Comment: Could you please explain what group = 1 does here?

Comment: @Norhther there is an excelent explanation of this _dummy aesthetic_ under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878813/ggplot-geom-bar-meaning-of-aesgroup-1). Basically, the default `group` aesthetic is set to `x` variable.

Comment: I read the post before, but I still don't understand the default behaviour in geom_line

Comment: @Norhther,I might be wrong, but as far, as I understand this: (1) if we supply only _x_ and _y_ variable, both discrete, ggplot recives task to draw a line 'through' them. However, (2) if we also  supply _color_ variable, that splits _x_-_y_ pairs into two (color) groups, then we get two lines, since default option is `group = x`, and _x_ and _y_ are now splited by `color = y ~ n`. But, (3) if we also add `group = 1` aesthetic, we tell ggplot, that despite the color grouping, we still want to keep whole dataset as one, consistent group.